# 403 Forbidden when posting to Spring boot/Mysql DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to post to my Spring Boot api to get the authentication token and username back. I am sending to it a username and password of a registered and enabled user. I have cors and csrf disabled in my SecurityConfig file but I am still getting a 403 forbidden. I know the username and passwords are correct. This project has its own JKS key store in its resources directory. What can be causing me to still get this 403 forbidden when posting?

SecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

AuthController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        authService.signup(registerRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Successful user registration", OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("accountVerification/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyAccount(@PathVariable String token) {
        authService.verifyAccount(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Account Activated Successfully", OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public AuthenticationResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        return authService.login(loginRequest);

    }


}
```

AuthService

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {


    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository;
    private final MailService mailService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @Transactional
    public void signup(RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(registerRequest.getUsername());
        user.setEmail(registerRequest.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()));
        user.setCreated(Instant.now());
        user.setEnabled(false);

        userRepository.save(user);

        generateVerificationToken(user);

        String token = generateVerificationToken(user);
        mailService.sendMail(new NotificationEmail("Please Activate your Account",
                user.getEmail(), "Thank you for signing up to this social network, " +
                "Use the following link to activate your account : " +
                "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/accountVerification/" + token));
    }

    private String generateVerificationToken(User user) {
        String token =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        VerificationToken verificationToken = new VerificationToken();
        verificationToken.setToken(token);
        verificationToken.setUser(user);

        verificationTokenRepository.save(verificationToken);
        return token;
    }

    public void verifyAccount(String token) {
        Optional<VerificationToken> verificationToken = verificationTokenRepository.findByToken(token);
        verificationToken.orElseThrow(() -> new SpringException("Invalid Token"));
        fetchUserAndEnable(verificationToken.get());
    }

    @Transactional
    void fetchUserAndEnable(VerificationToken verificationToken) {
        String username = verificationToken.getUser().getUsername();
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new SpringException("We could not find a user with the given username: " + username));
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    public AuthenticationResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),
                loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(authenticate);
        return new AuthenticationResponse(token, loginRequest.getUsername());

    }
}
```

UserDetailServiceImpl

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        User user = userOptional
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No user " +
                        "Found with username : " + username));

        return new org.springframework.security
                .core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                user.isEnabled(), true, true,
                true, getAuthorities("USER"));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {
        return singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is in your userdetailservice implementation?

Comment: @Erwin I added the userdetailsercvice implementation to the question

Comment: I think that it could be that when you signup your are not authenticated yet, so you should permit post requests to your signup endpoint in : .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/signup").permitAll() in your SecurityConfig

Comment: @HenriqueForlani When you signup, an activation email is sent to the user. In that email is a link that once you click it, you are activated. There is a field in the user table of "enabled". Once the user clicks the link in the activation email, that field changes from 0 to 1. I tried changing the ant matcher from ** to signup to login and all still gave me a 403 forbidden when posting with an activated account.

Comment: how about the getAuthorities? have u check the values of getAuthorities? try debug on getAuthorities